# Light-weight database engine for Delphi 1?

Tags: delphi, 16-bit

I'm looking for a light-weight database engine for Delphi 1 (don't ask, it's a long story). Delphi 1 is 16-bit. The engine should compile into the EXE. SQL would be nice, but not mandatory. Any info would be great. Thanks, Carl

Comment: Delphi 1? Sorry, but I'm asking. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, me too. WTF? You're obviously designing the software, so this can't be a real requirement.

Comment: Sounds like a bet. Good luck! :)

Comment: Delphi 1?  Sorry, I had to ask.  :-)

Comment: Long story? I've got time, spill the beans.

Comment: I can't speak for Carl, but I know one nice feature of 16 bit programs: they can access hardware IO ports without requiring a driver. I've been using a Delphi 1 dll with a Delphi 5 executable myself. "Thunking"... ah, those good old days :-)

Comment: Maybe that's the case of Carl, Giel........ As I cannot find another use of D1 except for the omnipresent demonstration of listbox dialog in Delphi 1 compiling and running in Delphi <n> (I saw that in all Borland/Codegear meetings I attended) ;-)

Comment: It's several months later now, and we haven't heard a single thing from 16-bit Carl anymore. Carl probably called Dispose(Carl), when modern Delphi all know that you should call Carl.Free.

Answer (score 2):

A 16-bit version of Microsoft Jet should be easy to integrate even with older versions of BDE (ODBC driver).

Otherwise you can use .db files (dBase - xBase), BDE should be able to handle them directly.

Answer (score 1):

How about [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?

Comment: Can SQLite be compiled to a 16-bit library?

Answer (score 1):

Turbo Power Btree Filer ? IIRC TP's is open source and TP was 16-bit.

Maybe this or the other DBF tool has 16-bit options. However the one I used (TDBF) doesn't afaik.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I used VB/ISAM with Delphi 1. It works well with Delphi 16bit even though it was originally made for VB. It is from [Software Source](http://www.1-software-source.com/). I think we were using v4.x.

Answer (score 0):

why not check on Delphi Super Pages web site. They use to maintain a complete code and component collections for Delphi 1.

I don't know the current situation though ;)

If you want I have a VBX based DB engine called VSData.

I never used Delphi 1 so I don't know as to how good it was at handling VBX. I have used this db engine as at that time this was the only engine to support storing multimedia files!